# MS Word Tempate Mail Merge Module

Tags: 7

I am in the planning stage of a new project that will probably use Drupal 7 and one of the requirements of the new site is that existing MS Word templates can be merged with data from our database to create a Word document or possibly a PDF. Some of the templates are for labels and therefore the formatting is crucial.

I have looked for existing modules but the only one that I found that comes close is Webform Document https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_document. It however is in development still and appears to use a regular Word document that you insert tokens into instead of a template.

The functionality that LiveDocx provides is what we would like but it is hosted offsite (we need all hosting onsite) unless you are willing to pay $5000 (outside of our budget).

There are also solutions that use COM functionality but I am not able to have Word installed on the hosting server.

Another possibility is to convert all the Word templates to PDF forms and use PDFForms https://www.drupal.org/project/fillpdf but the 7x version has a dependency on PDF Forms API which is in development and does not appear to be very active. It also looks like the same form could not be filled out multiple times if you have multiple records returned.

What are your suggestions for a dependable solution?

Thanks,
Jbr

Comment: I have a similar situation. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: No I did not find a good solution. The project is not proceeding so I have not looked anymore.